# Cannot set bartintcolor on iPhone 6 plus

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, iphone-6-plus, viewwillappear

So my problem is that I cannot set the bar tint color on an iPhone 6 plus. I can set the bar tint color for all other devices but for the iPhone 6 plus the bar tint won't change. Here is the code for the view controller. Additionally, this VC is being pushed onto the stack by a navigation controller. Any help is majorly appreciated all.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .redColor()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false
        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
```

This is the only thing that I am doing in the view controller and it doesn't work at all.

Comment: I think this will work fine. Where are you testing, on device or simulator?

Comment: I am testing on a device. On an iPhone 6 plus, an iPhone 5s and an iPhone 5.

Comment: Is it working fine on simulator?

Comment: I am going to test that now and get back to you in about 60 seconds.

Comment: Well, I tested your code in simulator and that works fine in 6s plus simulator

Comment: Yeah. And I've used this code a bunch of other times in a bunch of other contexts and it works fine. Just not with the 6 plus

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I solved the issue. For some reason, iPhone 6 plus calls

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .primaryGrayColor()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor()]
}
```

every time a new view controller is pushed onto a navigation stack. This does not happen in the iPhone 5, iPhone 5s, iPhone 6 or the iPhone 7.